# Showing a scrollbar with a ViewAnimator

Tags: android, scrollbar, viewanimator

I have a view animator that I am adding images to dynamically via a web service call.  However, the scroll bar refuses to show up no matter how many pics I add to the ViewAnimator.    Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewAnimator is not a scrollable layout. Adding a childview to view animator will not show the added view if you don't have a mechanism to call showNext or showPrevious.

Maybe you want to use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) instead? You nee to create a ScrollView that contains a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation. You can now add images dynamically to the LinearLayout and the ScrollView will increase in size.